# How to get my automated code to connect with Appium

Tags: android, intellij-idea, appium, appium-android

I am using a Linux/Ubuntu and trying to create an automated test case that logs the user in and logs out. However I just got my environment set up, and I know Appium doesn't have a GUI, and must be ran through the terminal. But my question is how do I know that my capabilities in my code connected with Appium, and is running my code? I created a "wait", because I need to pick up a button upon opening the app. I have included my current versions I'm using on the computer, my code to my automated test, and the terminal log. If you can resolve this I would really appreciate it.

```
Current Versions in use:
Ubuntu LTS 16.04
Selenium Standalone 3.11.0
Java_Client 2.2.0
IntelliJIdea: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 (Community Edition)
              Build #IC-173.4674.33, built on March 5, 2018
              JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b15 amd64
              JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
              Linux 4.8.0-56-generic

Code:
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestSonic {

String begin = 
"com.myapk.myapk.debug:id/onboarding_inner_orbit";


AndroidDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    File file = new File("/home/sonic/Documents/Automation", "Myapk.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Myapk.apk");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    capabilities.setCapability("clearSystemFiles", "True");

}

@Test
public void LogIn() {
    Wait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(begin)));

    driver.findElement(By.id(begin)).click();
    //WebElement starting = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(String.valueOf(By.id(begin)));
    //starting.click();

}

@After
public void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
}

}


   Appium Terminal:



[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.2 (REV 7ad6d98cedde01809e32d56ab8ced064f6f28175)
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1521754646829 (16:37:26 GMT-0500 (CDT))
[Appium] Merged W3C capabilities {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/sonic/Docu... into desiredCapabilities object {"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic....
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.37.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   app: /home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk
[Appium]   deviceName: Android Emulator
[Appium]   platformName: android
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: fe9c1ce5-c2b1-41ec-bb50-7c47b095b30e
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_161
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb from /home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Checking whether app is actually present
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","wait-for-device"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","echo","ping"]
[AndroidDriver] setDeviceLanguageCountry requires language or country.
[AndroidDriver] Got language: 'null' and country: 'null'
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","io.appium.settings"]
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","package","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt from /home/sonic/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt
[debug] [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.settings' package does not require upgrade (5 >= 5)
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.sdk"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 27
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 27
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","package","io.appium.settings"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","dump","io.appium.settings"]
[debug] [ADB] Got the following command chunks to execute: pm,grant,io.appium.settings,android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,;,pm,grant,io.appium.settings,android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION,;
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION",";"]
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION",";"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ps"]
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 27
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","appops","set","io.appium.settings","android:mock_location","allow"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.unlock
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for io.appium.unlock
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","package","io.appium.unlock"]
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[debug] [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.unlock' package does not require upgrade (2 >= 2)
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.release"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 8.1.0
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","wm","size"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.model"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model': Android SDK built for x86
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.manufacturer"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': Google
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest
[debug] [ADB] badging package: com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug
[debug] [ADB] badging act: com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug/com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity
[AndroidDriver] Remote apk path is /data/local/tmp/25a696eb8f803cd943564cda2e9d929a.apk
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ls","/data/local/tmp/25a696eb8f803cd943564cda2e9d929a.apk"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Checking if app is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug"]
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[AndroidDriver] Apk is already on remote and installed, resetting
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","force-stop","com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","clear","com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Extracting strings from apk /home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk null /tmp/com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug
[debug] [ADB] Extracting strings for language: default
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 27
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","persist.sys.locale"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'persist.sys.locale': 
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.locale"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.locale': en-US
[debug] [ADB] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
[debug] [ADB] Reading strings from converted strings.json
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","push","/tmp/com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug/strings.json","/data/local/tmp"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","forward","tcp:4724","tcp:4724"]
[debug] [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
[debug] [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
[debug] [UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","push","/home/sonic/.nvm/versions/node/v9.7.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-bootstrap/bootstrap/bin/AppiumBootstrap.jar","/data/local/tmp/"]
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ps"]
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[debug] [UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
[AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 27
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","start","-W","-n","com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug/com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Waiting up to 20000ms for activity matching pkg: 'com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug' and activity: 'com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity' to be focused
[debug] [ADB] Possible activities, to be checked: 'com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity'
[debug] [ADB] Getting focused package and activity
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/sonic/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
[debug] [ADB] Found package: 'com.sonic.sonicdrivein.debug' and fully qualified activity name : 'com.sonic.sonicdrivein.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session fe9c1ce5-c2b1-41ec-bb50-7c47b095b30e added to master session list
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1521754654676 (16:37:34 GMT-0500 (CDT))
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"android"},"app":"/home/sonic/Documents/Automation/Sonic.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"android","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"8.1.0","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"Google","appPackage":"com.myapk.myapk.debug","appWaitPackage":"com.myapk.myapk.debug","appActivity":"com.myapk.myapk.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity","appWaitActivity":"com.myapk.myapk.ui.screen.splash.SplashActivity"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 7857 ms - 888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Thread.sleep(60000); after the click.  If clicking the element had the same effect through code as it does when manually interacting with the app, then Appium is connected and working.

If the click doesn't work, there could be many possible reasons why.  Try clicking a different element and seeing if that has the desired result.